# Postgres 9.1.16 Hot Standby

Tags: postgresql, standby, write-ahead-logging, checkpoint

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.16 (and I cannot upgrade) with Hot Standby.

We have a few batches that perform some heavy writes, resulting in a lot of WAL bein produced in a short period of time.

The standby desynchronizes because the `pg_xlog` becomes full.

I could just increase the FS but I would like to understand.

I found out that with this version of PostgreSQL, the restartpoints are triggered only because of the `checkpoint_timeout` (5 min) parameter on the standby.

The primary checkpoints a lot (every 5 sec or so)  because of the WAL activity (triggered by `checkpoint_segments` (10) ). The result is that my standby doesn't recycle its WAL quickly enough and the FS becomes full before the next checkpoint.

Since checkpoints every 5s is "a bit too much", I tried to set `checkpoint_segments` to 50 on the primary and `checkpoint_timeout` to 30s in the standby. It's ugly but somehow the checkpoint timing are in synch and the standby doesn't "desync".

My questions are:

- In 9.1.16 and before. How did you handle restart point when it was triggered only by `checkpoint_timeout`?
- Can I do something else PostgreSQL wise than this ugly workaround ?
- I don't have much experience with pg in real world. my `pg_xlog` FS is 5G. Is it a normal size or is it way too small ?

PS: Feel free to ask me more info, it's my first post.

PS2: the article I found about `checkpoint_timeout` on standby http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTimpudRqHf8kFfQZxyMHsULYo79qwK5PCXxP21gt@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Set the `checkpoint_timeout` lower, as you did, to 30 seconds or so. I made sure to enable `log_checkpoints` in my `postgresql.conf` and used [check_postgres.pl](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres) to monitor the number of segments and replication lag.
   You can also set `checkpoint_completion_target=0` to adjust the checkpointing behavior as well. But really, on a replica, `checkpoint_timeout` is really the only way to keep the `pg_xlog` directory down in size on a replica.
   Additional reference here: [pgsql bugs #7801](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+U5nMKdf7odZzYNnoRkkCZmJpGEy=OQbU9Nan_zva_Rtzi2vw@mail.gmail.com)
2. Adjusting `checkpoint_timeout` is unfortunately the best option. There are some tips on dealing with pg_xlog filling up in this blog post: [Solving pg_xlog out of disk space problems](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/09/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres.html), but these mostly apply to a primary that's run out of space, and the panic related to that.
3. PostgreSQL WAL segments take up approximately this much room, according to the documentation for [9.1 WAL Configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-configuration.html):

   `(2 + checkpoint_completion_target) * checkpoint_segments + 1` or `checkpoint_segments + wal_keep_segments + 1` files

   So if you do the math like this for example, with a `checkpoint_completion_target=0.9` and `checkpoint_segments = 50`:

   `(2 + 0.9) * 50 + 1 = 146 * 16MB = 2336 MB`

   Which is only about 45% of your `5 GB` of your `pg_xlog` filesystem. So long as you aren't getting checkpoint warnings in your logs, and the space isn't in danger of being completely used up, 5 GB should be fine. Using these formulas, you should be able to appropriately size your `pg_xlog` filesystem for your usage.

   Greg Smith has a lovely chart in PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance, referenced here: [Server Configuration Tuning Practices](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/server-configuration-tuning-postgresql). I would also recommend the book as a reference, even though it's a bit old, because a lot of the information in it is still quite applicable.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps a lot. I looked at the source and found out that the checkpoint_segments is used on the standby too but I am understand the impression that the length of the restant point depends upon the value of checkpoint_timeout. I need to verify this. I Will post again.